# Why here the self is MyClass?

Tags: ruby

```
class MyClass
  def MyFun
    puts self
  end
end

mine = MyClass.new
mine.MyFun   # => #<MyClass:0x10a3ee670>
```

Since module, class, def all changes scope, here self should be MyFun instead of MyClass as it's inside def...end. Why still it remains at MyClass?

Comment: I'm no ruby expert, but isn't MyFun a method, not a class? self refers to the object instance, not the method name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***scope of `self`:***

> *Inside the class definition,`self` is always the `class constants(instance of Class)` itself.(except the instance methods).*
>
> *Inside the instance methods,`self` is the instances of that class constant which just called the respective methods.*

```
p RUBY_VERSION

class Foo

    def self.talk
    p "here SELF is-> #{self}"
    end
    
    def display
    p "here SELF is-> #{self}"
    end
    
    p "here SELF is-> #{self}"

end
Foo.talk
foo = Foo.new
foo.display
class << foo
p "here SELF is-> #{self}"
end
```

*Output:*

```
"2.0.0"
"here SELF is-> Foo"
"here SELF is-> Foo"
"here SELF is-> #<Foo:0x1fc7fa0>"
"here SELF is-> #<Class:#<Foo:0x1fc7fa0>>"
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` is the current context object. `MyFun` is not an object, but a method — specifically, it's an instance method of MyClass. So inside `MyFun`, `self` will be the instance of MyClass that is executing `MyFun`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `MyFun` is an instance method, so `self` is in fact an instance of `MyClass`.

That *thing* `mine.MyFun` is returning is fact the instance literal. If it were a class literal it would be jsut plainly `MyClass`. Test it yourself

```
class Example
  def asdf
    self
  end
end

Example.new.asdf.class #=> Example
```

Comment: That isn't a literal, it's just the string returned by `inspect`. You can't do `#<MyClass:0x10a3ee670>.MyFun` to call the method again.

Comment: Yeap, your right, I slipped the `puts` part. It will work with my example though.